# PropertyEditor is not called on AJAX (JSON) request

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have problem with Ajax request on form submit. The form contains these stringify JSON data:

```
{"articleContent":"<p>aaa</p>","title":"Po vyplnění titulku aktuality budete","header":"aa","enabled":false,"timestamp":"1358610697521","publishedSince":"03.01.2013 00:00","publishedUntil":"","id":"10"}
```

When json contains **"03.01.2013 00:00"** value, server respons is **400 Bad Request**

Problem is that, custom DateTimePropertyEditor (which is registrated with @InitBinder) is not called, and DateTime in String format is not conveted. Have you any idea How to solve this problem?

**Controllers mapped method, which is processing request**

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/admin/article/edit/{articleId}", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"content-type=application/json"})
public @ResponseBody JsonResponse  processAjaxUpdate(@RequestBody Article article, @PathVariable Long articleId){
    JsonResponse response = new JsonResponse();
    Article persistedArticle = articleService.getArticleById(articleId);
    if(persistedArticle == null){
        return response;
    }
    List<String> errors = articleValidator.validate(article, persistedArticle);

    if(errors.size() == 0){
        updateArticle(article, persistedArticle);
        response.setStatus(JsonStatus.SUCCESS);
        response.setResult(persistedArticle.getChanged().getMillis());
    }else{
        response.setResult(errors);
    }

    return response;
}
```

**InitBinder**

```
 @InitBinder
        public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
            binder.registerCustomEditor(DateTime.class, this.dateTimeEditor);
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem with using **@JsonDeserialize**

```
@JsonDeserialize(using=DateTimeDeserializer.class)
public DateTime getPublishedUntil() {
    return publishedUntil;
}
```

I have to implemetd custom Deserializer.

```
    public class DateTimeDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<DateTime> {

    private DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(Constants.DATE_TIME_FORMAT);

    public DateTimeDeserializer(){
        super(DateTime.class);
    }

    @Override
    public DateTime deserialize(JsonParser json, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            try {
                if(StringUtils.isBlank(json.getText())){
                    return null;
                }
                return formatter.parseDateTime(json.getText());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                return null;
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not handled by a Property Editor - which acts on form fields and not on json bodies. To handle a non-standard date format in a json, you will have to customize the underlying [ObjectMapper](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html). Assuming you are using jackson 2.0+, these are what you can do:

a. Tag the publishedSince field with an annotation that tells Object mapper the format for date - based on instructions [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling):

```
public class Article{
    ...
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="MM.dd.yyyy HH:mm")
    private Date publishedSince;
}
```

b. Or second option is to modify the ObjectMapper itself, this could be global though, so may not work for you:

```
public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
    public CustomObjectMapper(){
        super.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yyyy hh:mm"));
    }   
}
```

and configure this with Spring MVC:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven> 
   <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
       <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
           <property name="objectMapper">
               <bean class="..CustomObjectMapper"/>
           </property>
       </bean>
   </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I tried this solution, but it doesn't work. I'm using Joda DateTime, may be this problem?

Answer (score 0):

With Spring MVC 4.2.1.RELEASE, you need to use the new Jackson2 dependencies as below for the Deserializer to work.

Dont use this

```
<dependency>  
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>  
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>  
            <version>1.9.12</version>  
        </dependency>
```

Use this instead.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Also use com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer and  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize for the deserialization and not the classes from org.codehaus.jackson